# What is an “invited submission” to a journal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, terminology

The website of the journal Philosophy and Phenomenological Research says:

> This site only accepts invited submissions.

In general, what is an invited submission? Is this how special issues of journals are published? Why would a journal invite submissions? How does publishing as an invited submission look compared to a normal submission?

Comment: We don't know. Ask them. You didn't even tell us what journal it was!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Question edited.

Comment: A link to the journal page with that quote might help.

Comment: While it does not answer your question, I recommend that you read all the information on [this site](https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/pandpr).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft in fact your link even answers the question... Reading the front page might have helped the OP ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The answer is found on the front page of the journal...

Comment: @OBu where in the front page?

Comment: "The journal has temporarily stopped accepting new submissions, and will resume accepting them on November 1, 2018. This accords with our practice for about a decade, though stop and resume dates vary depending on backlog size and growth in that academic year. (Authors who have been invited to revise papers can still submit them through the "Manuscripts with Decisions" link in their author center. ) "

Comment: After edits from other users, this seems like a straightforward terminology question (about terminology familiar in the social sciences), and I'm not sure why it was closed. The answer specifically about whether that journal will accept submissions is now clear, but that statement does not actually answer the question about what an invited submission is.

Comment: @cactus_pardner Me neither. It seems some people are expeditious in closing!

Comment: Often, journals that only publish reviews, i.e. Progress in Aerospace Sciences, only accept invited (or commissioned) papers.

Answer (score 8):

An invited submission is as the name implies, something which the editors of the journal invited. You have probably seen this kind of invitation email - "we would like to invite you to write something on [this topic]. Are you interested?"

It may or may not be related to special issues. Special issues are entire issues formed around that single topic (or conference). If the journal is inviting for a special issue, it will say so in the invitation - "we are publishing this special issue and you're an expert on the topic, so we would like to invite you ...". However it's also possible to be invited for regular issues.

A journal invites submissions for several reasons:

1. If the journal can get big names to write for them, it raises the profile of the journal as well as (hopefully) generates citations. Other researchers are more likely to submit if famous researchers also submit to the journal. This is the most important reason.
2. The journal may lack papers. The big journals may receive more papers than they can publish, but there're also a lot of small journals that struggle to fill their issues.
3. The journal may want to expand. This could be its author pool (invite people who've never published in the journal before), its author country pool (invite people from countries who rarely publish in the journal), or its issue count (increase in issue count is a reason to charge higher subscription prices).

Finally, in principle, invited submissions are more prestigious than regular submissions. That's because the author can safely say that someone out there thinks they're an expert in the field. It's especially good if the invitation comes from a famous researcher. However: many poor-quality journals will also resort to invitations to solicit papers. Their aim is merely to get papers, and they don't really care who is writing or even what topic the paper is on. You will have to use your judgment. In my experience, a personalized email coming from an established researcher in your field is the best kind of invitation.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an invited submission for your CV or tenure review may vary based on whether that journal still subjects it to peer review and/or whether the journal and the editors inviting you are well-regarded (as Allure alluded). As mentioned in [a Chronicle of Higher Education online forum](http://www.chronicle.com/forums/index.php?topic=79269.0;imode), invited submissions are sometimes "not subject to regular peer review," while in other cases, they are still peer reviewed, as in [this protocol from ACM TODS](https://tods.acm.org/ICDTPapersPolicy.cfm).